# ADO.net SqlDataAdapter.Update bulk insert how to detect primary key violations?

Tags: .net, t-sql, ado.net

I am looking at a problem I have with some older Data Access code that uses `SqlDataAdapter` to do bulk insert operations. The destination table has a primary key constraint, and I need to identify any rows I try to insert that violate this primary key (i.e. detect duplicates) and take action on these rows.

Most of the time, the inserts will *not* have any duplicates, but I do need to handle the cases when there is. Via experimentation, it was found that doing this bulk insert and then looking for violations was faster that individually checking each row for it's existence before adding.

The code to do this is as follows.

```
foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet.Tables)
  {
    try
    {
      List<string> columns = new List<string>();
      foreach (DataColumn column in dataTable.Columns)
        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);

      string commandText = "select " + String.Join(",", columns.ToArray()) + " from " + dataTable.TableName;

      SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn);
      SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand);
      dataAdapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;
      SqlCommandBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
      dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      // No exception should be thrown with ContinueUpdateOnError = true
    }
  }

  return dataSet;
```

Note the `dataAdapter.ContinueUpdateOnError = true;` means that any errors do NOT throw any exceptions (the exception block is never entered)

So, once the above has been run, we can look for any errors, including any primary key violations, by using code as below...

```
foreach (DataTable dataTable in dataSet)
{
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
    { 
        if (dataRow.HasErrors)
        {
           // Here I want to detect if the error was a primary key violation, or something else
        }
    }
}
```

So, I can detect the rows that have *some sort of error* via the .HasErrors as above, but I can't see a good way to detect that this error was a primary key violation. There *is* a RowError property, but this is just text something like... `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_MYKEY'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.MY_TABLE'. The duplicate key value is (6215).
The statement has been terminated.`

The only way I can see to distinguish this from some other error (e.g. a disk error etc) is by searching for some of the above text, however this does not seem very robust or good practice (the error text may change, or if running a different language / culture the text will also be different)

The dataRow also has an `ErrorState` property (which just always seems to say `Added`, and there is also an error object but this just has the same text, and no real extra information.

Is there a way I get get any better information on the actual error, e.g. if it is a primary key violation, or otherwise in the above scheme?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to bulk insert your data into an empty staging table and then run a stored procedure that merges the data from the staging table into the real table. If its not an issue, you can also adjust your query to exclude duplicates.

I also recommend you use SqlBulkCopy for bulk operations. From my experience, SqlBulkCopy is the fastest way to bulk load data in .NET to SQL Server. There are also a lot of useful properties you can set.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx